# Jenkins-Deployment failure, Build successful

Tags: jenkins, git, jenkins-plugins, java, tomcat

I have been trying to work on Jenkins and I'm able to Build the code but unable to deploy on to the Tomcat server. Have checked the users.xml file and

```
Started by user nakul
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /home/ubuntu/.jenkins/workspace/Development
using credential 1da4e373-a6ab-4c02-8231-6c3040786f0b
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/nakul-crypto/maven.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/nakul-crypto/maven.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress -- https://github.com/nakul-crypto/maven.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 7599ae0e083b03eb84d05b6606b3dc0df36b45f8 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 7599ae0e083b03eb84d05b6606b3dc0df36b45f8 # timeout=10
Commit message: "maven"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 7599ae0e083b03eb84d05b6606b3dc0df36b45f8 # timeout=10
[Development] $ mvn package
[[1;34mINFO[m] Scanning for projects...
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 
[[1;33mWARNING[m] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example.maven-project:server:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[[1;33mWARNING[m] Reporting configuration should be done in <reporting> section, not in maven-site-plugin <configuration> as reportPlugins parameter.
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 
[[1;33mWARNING[m] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example.maven-project:webapp:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[[1;33mWARNING[m] Reporting configuration should be done in <reporting> section, not in maven-site-plugin <configuration> as reportPlugins parameter.
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 
[[1;33mWARNING[m] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example.maven-project:maven-project:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[[1;33mWARNING[m] Reporting configuration should be done in <reporting> section, not in maven-site-plugin <configuration> as reportPlugins parameter. @ line 56, column 24
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 
[[1;33mWARNING[m] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 
[[1;33mWARNING[m] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[[1;33mWARNING[m] 
[[1;33mWARNING[m] The project com.example.maven-project:maven-project:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT uses prerequisites which is only intended for maven-plugin projects but not for non maven-plugin projects. For such purposes you should use the maven-enforcer-plugin. See https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1mReactor Build Order:[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] Maven Project                                                      [pom]
[[1;34mINFO[m] Server                                                             [jar]
[[1;34mINFO[m] Webapp                                                             [war]
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--------------< [0;36mcom.example.maven-project:maven-project[0;1m >---------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1mBuilding Maven Project 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                [1/3][m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------< [0;36mcom.example.maven-project:server[0;1m >------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1mBuilding Server 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                       [2/3][m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources[m [1m(default-resources)[m @ [36mserver[0;1m ---[m
[debug] execute contextualize
[[1;34mINFO[m] Using 'utf-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[[1;34mINFO[m] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/ubuntu/.jenkins/workspace/Development/server/src/main/resources
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile[m [1m(default-compile)[m @ [36mserver[0;1m ---[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources[m [1m(default-testResources)[m @ [36mserver[0;1m ---[m
[debug] execute contextualize
[[1;34mINFO[m] Using 'utf-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[[1;34mINFO[m] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/ubuntu/.jenkins/workspace/Development/server/src/test/resources
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile[m [1m(default-testCompile)[m @ [36mserver[0;1m ---[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-surefire-plugin:2.11:test[m [1m(default-test)[m @ [36mserver[0;1m ---[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] Surefire report directory: /home/ubuntu/.jenkins/workspace/Development/server/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Running com.example.TestGreeter
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.116 sec

Results :

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar[m [1m(default-jar)[m @ [36mserver[0;1m ---[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------< [0;36mcom.example.maven-project:webapp[0;1m >------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1mBuilding Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                       [3/3][m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources[m [1m(default-resources)[m @ [36mwebapp[0;1m ---[m
[debug] execute contextualize
[[1;34mINFO[m] Using 'utf-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[[1;34mINFO[m] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/ubuntu/.jenkins/workspace/Development/webapp/src/main/resources
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile[m [1m(default-compile)[m @ [36mwebapp[0;1m ---[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] No sources to compile
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources[m [1m(default-testResources)[m @ [36mwebapp[0;1m ---[m
[debug] execute contextualize
[[1;34mINFO[m] Using 'utf-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[[1;34mINFO[m] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/ubuntu/.jenkins/workspace/Development/webapp/src/test/resources
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile[m [1m(default-testCompile)[m @ [36mwebapp[0;1m ---[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] No sources to compile
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-surefire-plugin:2.11:test[m [1m(default-test)[m @ [36mwebapp[0;1m ---[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] No tests to run.
[[1;34mINFO[m] Surefire report directory: /home/ubuntu/.jenkins/workspace/Development/webapp/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-war-plugin:2.2:war[m [1m(default-war)[m @ [36mwebapp[0;1m ---[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] Packaging webapp
[[1;34mINFO[m] Assembling webapp [webapp] in [/home/ubuntu/.jenkins/workspace/Development/webapp/target/webapp]
[[1;34mINFO[m] Processing war project
[[1;34mINFO[m] Copying webapp resources [/home/ubuntu/.jenkins/workspace/Development/webapp/src/main/webapp]
[[1;34mINFO[m] Webapp assembled in [33 msecs]
[[1;34mINFO[m] Building war: /home/ubuntu/.jenkins/workspace/Development/webapp/target/webapp.war
[[1;34mINFO[m] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1mReactor Summary for Maven Project 1.0-SNAPSHOT:[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] Maven Project ...................................... [1;32mSUCCESS[m [  0.010 s]
[[1;34mINFO[m] Server ............................................. [1;32mSUCCESS[m [  2.344 s]
[[1;34mINFO[m] Webapp ............................................. [1;32mSUCCESS[m [  0.776 s]
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1;32mBUILD SUCCESS[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] Total time:  3.453 s
[[1;34mINFO[m] Finished at: 2020-02-06T19:47:13Z
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[DeployPublisher][INFO] Attempting to deploy 1 war file(s)
[DeployPublisher][INFO] Deploying /home/ubuntu/.jenkins/workspace/Development/webapp/target/webapp.war to container Tomcat 8.x Remote with context testapp
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to redeploy [/home/ubuntu/.jenkins/workspace/Development/webapp/target/webapp.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:188)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:81)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:167)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:136)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1075)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1058)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeployFile(CargoContainerAdapter.java:133)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeployFile(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:95)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:113)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1878)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:710)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:527)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:167)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:882)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:895)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:169)
    ... 18 more
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:710)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:527)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:167)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:882)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:895)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:169)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:81)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:167)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:136)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1075)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1058)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeployFile(CargoContainerAdapter.java:133)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeployFile(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:95)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:113)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1878)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be an issue with Tomcat URL you are using. Either you are using "HTTP" in deployment when server is expecting HTTPS or vice versa.

> hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428) Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Have a look at this answer [unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection-exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532273/unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection-exception)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you were right. It was the URL.